# how to start two jboss eap 6.4 on the same machine

Tags: jboss

I want to start two or more jboss eap 6.4 in the domain, but when I started the second domain I got this warning:

> [Server:server-one] 15:34:35,606 WARN  [org.hornetq.core.client]
>   (hornetq-discovery-group-thread-dg-group1) HQ212034: There are more
>   than one servers on the network broadcasting the same node id. You
>   will see this message exactly once (per node) if a node is restarted,
>   in which case it can be safely ignored. But if it is logged
>   continuously it means you really do have more than one node on the
>   same network active concurrently with the same node id. This could
>   occur if you have a backup node active at the same time as its live
>   node. nodeID=14bdbf74-f56c-11e4-a65f-738aa3641190

I cannot get this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You must have copied the node from other node. Delete messagingjournal from data directory from all the nodes and restart all the nodes again.